# Enviar tarefa pelo server para clients nodejs

Tags: node.js, socket

Estou utilizando socket.io  e fazendo um server e client em nodejs. A comunicação entre eles está funcionando. Servidor recebe notificação quando cliente conecta e desconecta. Estou precisando agora enviar tarefas do server para o client e armazenar em um array por clientes essas mensagens

server.js

```
io.on( 'connection', ( socket ) =>{
console.log( 'Nova conexão, exibindo o ID desse cliente:', socket.id )

if( socket.id )
{
    socket.on('task', ( task ) => {

        let arrTask = [];

        cron.schedule('*/10 * * * * *', () => {
            console.log( task )
        })

        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            console.log( 'Cliente desconectado' )
        })

    })

}
})
```

client.js

```
socket.on( 'connect', () =>{

  console.log( "Cliente conectou" );
  socket.emit( 'task', 'Cliente '  + socket.id + ', recebi sua tarefa' );

})

socket.on('msg', (msg) => {

  console.log( msg );

});
```

Se alguém puder me auxiliar ficaria grato. Ah, me desculpem mas não consegui colar o codigo certo.

Comment: @Sorack obrigado por ter editado, não estava conseguindo. Saberia me auxiliar nessa questão do código?

Answer (score 0):

Acho que não entendi exatamente ... Mas estou confuso um pouco com o seu código.

Vamos partir do principio básico:

socket.emit => envia uma mensagem

socket.on => fica escutando o canal e assim que receber faz algo.

no lado do cliente:

```
socket.on( 'connect', () =>{
  let tarefa = {dados: "fazer algo", tempo: 50, teste: false};
  console.log( "Conectou com o servidor de socket" );
  socket.emit( 'task', tarefa); // emite a tarefa assim que conecta no servidor.
});

socket.on('mensagem-retorno', (msg) => {
  console.log( msg );
});
```

Já no server.js

```
io.on( 'connection', ( socket ) =>{
    console.log( 'Nova conexão, exibindo o ID desse cliente:', socket.id )

    if( socket.id )
    {
        socket.on('task', ( tarefa) => {
            // essa parte de armazenar eu não sei como você irá fazer.
            console.log( tarefa ); // << sua tarefa está aqui. 
            let arrTask = [];



            cron.schedule('*/10 * * * * *', () => {
                console.log( tarefa )
            })

            socket.on('disconnect', () => {
                socket.emit('mensagem-retorno', 'Sua tarefa foi recebida e processada'); // o cliente vai estar observando o "canal" mensagem-retorno
                console.log( 'Cliente desconectado' );
            });

        });

    }
});
```

Conseguiu entender? se você quiser mandar a mensagem para todos os clientes conectados ao servidor, você deve usar broadcast.

Comment: obrigado @Thomaz Diogo Cimin

Comment: Conseguiu rodar sem problemas? Se tiver mais dúvida comenta ai.